# A proof in Desargues' geometry

Tags: geometry

The question is: Prove in Desargues' geometry that if a, b, c are three lines where a is parallel to both b and c then b and c intersect at the pole of a.

Desargues' Geometry has the following Axioms:

1. There exists at least one point
2. Each point has at least one polar
3. Each line has at most one pole
4. Each pair of points is on at most one line
5. Each line has exactly 3 points on it
6. If line a does not contain point P, then every polar of P intersects a

So, I have been working on this proof and figure I will
Let a, b, c be three lines
Let a be parallel to b and c

Then I somehow have to show P is the pole of a and that b and c intersect at it

I've considered a proof by contradiction saying a pole of a is on b by assuming it isn't but I am not sure how to start that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I helped layout your question a bit but it still is seems to be missing some parts ( unfinished sentences? ). Except for making the question have a nice layout and formulation, sometimes it can also help in the process to get help from others to show some own efforts, like the start of your own attempted proof.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $a$ has a pole, that pole is unique according to 3. Let's call it $P$.
2. If $P$ does not lie on $b$, then $b$ must intersect $a$ due to 6. This contradicts the assumed parallelity, so by contradiction we now know that $P$ must lie on $b$.
3. Likewise for $c$. So $P$ lies on both $b$ and $c$, so it is their intersection.

This is *incomplete,* though: the first step assumes that $a$ *has* a pole, which doesn't follow from the axioms in a trivial way, and which hasn't been justified. This appears to be the really tricky part.

I didn't know about Desargues' geometry with this meaning. I wonder what models of Desargues' geometry do exist. If the only such model is Desargues' configuration, then it should be possible to show that the pole-polar relation is in fact $1:1$, so every point has exactly one polar and every line exactly one pole. If you have this established as a theorem, you could use it here. Otherwise it might be a useful direction of investigation.